# Animating recyclerview when scrolling

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, objectanimator

I watched this youtube video by Slidenerd:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8ifO1m9g_Q

He suggested that if you want to use animation in your recyclerview, use the following code inside your onBindViewHolder code of the recyclerview:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorTranslateY;
if (position > previousPosition) { //this should only activate animation when scrolling up
    objectAnimatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", 200, 0 );
    objectAnimatorTranslateY.setDuration(300);
    objectAnimatorTranslateY.start();
}
previousPosition = position;
```

I have instantiate the previousPosition as a member variable to 0.

The code animates the items in the recyclerview so that it appears as to fly in from the bottom of the screen when you scroll.

The code is working but what I'm failing to achieve is how to prevent the code from running when the list first appears on the screen.

I do not want the list items to be animated when you first open the app but only when it is scrolling up. How do I stop the animator from starting when recyclerview first appears on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a hack but I think you could check the **Y**-position of the item and compare it to the **ScreenHeight**. And if `view.getX() > getScreenHeight` then run appearing animation.